# Android GridView : images shuffled/mixed up on scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, android-listview

Some images of my GridView are mixed up when I scroll. I don't understand why...

Here is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    Item curItem = items.get(position);

ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null){  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

    convertView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.squareImageView = (SquareImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    holder.itemNameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemNameTextView);

    holder.deleteImageView = (SquareImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteImageView);

}        
else
{            
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}


if(!curItem.loadingLaunched ) 
{
    curItem.loadingLaunched = true;
    curItem.loadImage();
}

if(curItem.bm != null)
{
    holder.squareImageView.setImageBitmap(curItem.bm);

}


if(curItem.title != null)
{
    holder.itemNameTextView.setText(curItem.title);
}       

return convertView;

    }


static class ViewHolder {           
        SquareImageView squareImageView;
        TextView itemNameTextView;              
        SquareImageView deleteImageView ;       
    }
```

Anybody sees how to solve this issue ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem !

In my Item class, I add in my loadImage method something like that :

```
bm=null;   // Bad idea to init this BitMap to null !!!!!!


 try {       
        UrlImage = new URL (file);
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) UrlImage.openConnection(); 
        bm= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
     }
    catch{...}
```

This is a very bad idea because curItem.bm remains null as long as the remote image is not loaded. And a gridView does not like loading null images (it mixes everything).

So, in the constructor of the item class (warning : really important to put it in the constructor, strangely not working if put just instead of "bm=null"), I put this:

```
 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MyApp.appContext.getResources(), R.drawable.default_image);
```

And no more mixing !